# How to Write Conditional Statement Based on Parent

Tags: python, kivy, self

Goal: Write conditional statement based on the parent.

My approach: I executed `print(self.parent)`to see what the parent is called. In my case, `<Screen name='notags'>`was printed. I then tried to write a conditional statement based on that output (shown below).

Python Code:

```
        print(self.parent)
        if self.parent == <Screen name='notags'>:
            button_share.bind(on_press=self.update_buttons_assignoverride)
        self.box_share.add_widget(button_share)
```

I didn't really expect that to work, but am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print use `__str__` to get the text you are going to print, so it is not correct to compare with that string, you have to compare the names:

```
print(self.parent)
if self.parent.name == 'notags':
    button_share.bind(on_press=self.update_buttons_assignoverride)
self.box_share.add_widget(button_share)
```